# Non-determinstic choice with amb-operator

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming, continuations, non-deterministic

Is it possible to implement [McCarthy's `amb`-operator](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2005/10/11/amb-operator) for non-deterministic choice in C#?

Apparently .NET lacks continuation support but `yield return` could be useful. Would this be possible in other static .NET-languages like F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `yield return` does a form of continuation. Although for many useful cases, Linq provides functional operators that allow you to plug together a lazy sequence generator, so in fact in C# 3 it isn't necessary to use `yield return` so much (except when adding more Linq-style extensions of your own to plug gaps in the library, e.g. Zip, Unfold).

In the example we factorise an integer by brute force. Essentially the same example in C# can be done with the built-in Linq operators:

```
var factors = Enumerable.Range(2, 100)
        .Join(Enumerable.Range(2, 100), 
              n => 1, n => 1, (i, j) => new { i, j })
        .First(v => v.i*v.j == 481);

Console.WriteLine("Factors are " + factors.i + ", " + factors.j);
```

Here the starting points are my two calls to `Enumerable.Range`, which is built-in to Linq but you could implement yourself as:

```
IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int stop)
{
    for (int n = start; n < stop; n++)
        yield return n;
}
```

There are two odd parameters, the `n => 1`, `n => 1` parameters to `Join`. I'm picking 1 as the key value for `Join` to use when matching up items, hence all combinations will match and so I get to test every combination of numbers from the ranges.

Then I turn the pair of values into a kind of tuple (an anonymous type) with:

```
(i, j) => new { i, j })
```

Finally, I pick the first such tuple for which my test is satisfied:

```
.First(v => v.i*v.j == 481);
```

**Update**

The code inside the call to `First` need not be merely a short test expression. It can be a whole lot of imperative code which needs to be "restarted" if the test fails:

```
.First(v => 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Aren't lambdas powerful things?");

           return v.i*v.j == 481;
       );
```

So the part of the program that potentially needs to be restarted with different values goes in that lambda. Whenever that lambda wants to restart itself with different values, it just returns false - the equivalent of calling `amb` with no arguments.

Comment: Nice code - But it has a quite different effect than amb. Amb chooses its value such that the whole code doesn't fail, not just the following computation.

Comment: The "restart" has to be limited to a particular context, however it is implemented; specifically, it would be silly to restart the entire program including all the work done before the amb variables were introduced! In my version, this is made clear by channeling the amb variables into a sequence, and then the restartable context is the lambda passed to First - see the update above which may make this clearer. The code in the lambda may be arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: Agreed, nice code, but this is a deterministic brute force implementation. This not a concurrent non-deterministic implementation, which I believe are two of the key attributes of implementing an AMB operator. As a side note, since this post, Rx was released and that does have an Amb operator.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer to your question, but it may get you what you want.

amb is used for nondeterministic computing. As you may know, Prolog is a nondeterministic language using the notion of unification to bind values to variables (basically what amb ends up doing).

There IS an implementation of this functionality in C#, called YieldProlog. As you guessed, the yield operator is an important requisite for this.

http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/